# Sonata Admin One to Many relations

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I started working with SonataAdmin Bundle today, and i can't figure out OneToMany relations. My User can follow(obserwowane) offerts

Entities:

```
class Obserwowane {

  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  protected $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Oferty",inversedBy="obserwowane")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="oferta", referencedColumnName="id_oferty", onDelete="CASCADE")
   */
  protected $oferta;

  /**
   *
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="obserwowane")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  protected $user;
}
```

.

```
class User {

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Obserwowane", mappedBy="user")
   */
  public $obserwowane;
}
```

.

```
class Oferty {

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Obserwowane", mappedBy="oferta")
   */
  protected $obserwowane;
}
```

My servies.yml -> http://pastebin.com/biNCLhNt

I would like to display followed offers in User form in SonataAdminBundle. I would like also to have it editable.

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('id', 'integer', array('label' => 'id'))
        ->add('username', 'text', array('label' => 'Username'))
        ->add('email', 'text', array('label' => 'e-mail'))
        ->add('password', 'text', array('label' => 'Password'))
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define obserwowane as ArrayCollection and add getter and setter methods so sonata will use them to operate with Obserwowane array of entities.

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class user{

// ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->obserwowane = new ArrayCollection;
    }

    /**
     * Get obserwowane 
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
      public function getObserwowane ()
      {
          return $this->obserwowane ;
      }


      public function setObserwowane (ArrayCollection $obserwowane )
      {
          $this->obserwowane  = $obserwowane ;

          return $this;
      }

      /**
       * Add Obserwowane
       *
       * @param Obserwowane $obserwowane
       * @return Obserwowane
       */
      public function addObserwowane (Obserwowane $obserwowane )
      {
          $this->obserwowane[] = $obserwowane;

          return $this;
      }

      /**
       * Remove Obserwowane
       *
       * @param Obserwowane $obserwowane
       */
      public function removeObserwowane(Obserwowane $obserwowane)
      {
          $this->obserwowane->removeElement($obserwowane);
      }

}
```

Finally add obserwowane field in formMapper

```
$formMapper
 ->add('obserwowane')
```

**Update**

To add or remove user for Obserwowane entity add those functions to Obserwowaneclass

```
class Obserwowane{

    // ..

    /**
     * Set User
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get User
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

And in sonata

```
$formMapper
 ->add(user)
```

Comment: It seems like its working -> http://imgur.com/MdXNir7 . The only problem is that delete is not working. Any ideas?
Thanks for your help, really appreciate it :)

Comment: Should work.  Compare removeObserwowane function code. I've edited it's annotation once so you could get wrong code. If everything is ok see if it's returning any error. Check app/logs/dev.log and prod.log for errors.

Comment: I double checked the code you provided, but its still doesnt work. Ive checked the logs but im not sure for what im looking for... logs-> http://pastebin.com/7USdWZ0X
data tab -> http://imgur.com/gvuxmvM

edit: cleared cache still doesnt work :/

Comment: ok, let's try to debug it this way. Delete dev.log and click on delete icon then check dev.log again.

Comment: Well i did that before i post. Still checked again, and logs remain the same.

Comment: also try adding nullable true attribute  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)

Comment: Still doesnt work... I have 
public function __toString() {
        return (string) $this->id;
    } in obserwowane entity, is it causing the problem? I found out that adding doesnt work too.

Comment: Still log is very big. It shouldn't be that way in case of one simple action. I'll check it tomorrow.

Comment: no this function shows how entity is called in sonata.

Comment: Still doesnt work. I dont understand this, everything seems to be ok. I copied entire code here http://pastebin.com/cgDeTxNR . No idea whats the cause. I even added comments to check if its something wrong about ObserwowaneEntity, but its not working too. I had the same issue with EasyAdminBundle, thats why i wanted to check Sonata :/

Comment: find me in room symfony2

Comment: well, the problem is i need 20 reputation to talk in rooms :x